# Prove $\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}} +\frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}} +\frac{c^{2}}{a^{2}} +\frac{15abc}{4}\geq \frac{27}{4}$ for $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+abc=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Prove:
> $$\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}} +\frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}} +\frac{c^{2}}{a^{2}} +\frac{15abc}{4}\geq \frac{27}{4}$$ for $a,b,c>0$ such that $$a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+abc=4.$$

I tried to note $a=\cos A$,... because of a known identity, I used $s=\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}} +\frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}} +\frac{c^{2}}{a^{2}} \geq \frac{a}{b} +\frac{b}{c} +\frac{c}{a}$ and $s\geq \frac{a}{c} +\frac{b}{a} +\frac{c}{b}$, and then I added them. Another suggestion? Please!
I also noted $s=a+b+c,p=ab+bc+ac, r=abc$. The condion is equivalent with $s^2-2p+r=4$. Using the 2 inequalities which I mentioned above $\implies s\ge(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)/(2abc)-1$, and then is enought to prove that $2sp+15r^2\ge33r$, but I don't know if the last one is correct inequality. You can try to prove that. I'm desperate.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! What are a,b,c, and A? Please edit your question and add context, and it's also unclear what your question even is.

Comment: @user Wasn't it $\frac{15abc}{4}$ in the original question

Comment: @VyomYadav I did change nothing there.

Comment: 15abc/4 is correct.

Answer (score 2):

With the following [link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2426h1034364_a2b2c2abc4_and_its_consequences) $a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4 \Rightarrow abc \leq 1$ thus the maximum value is $1$ and we assume that $a=1,b=1,c=1$. $\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}+\frac{15abc}{4}$, we substitut $1$ we get exactly $\frac{27}{4}$, this is the maximum value that we could get. If $a,b,c$ is less that $1$ we could not reach $\frac{27}{4}$.So $\mathbf{a,b,c=1}$.

Comment: "this is the maximum value that we could get". This should be the minimal value. Your proof does not hold.

Comment: @taiwan12 obviously by substituting 1 we get 27/4, this is the case for equality, and I also tried to use abc <= 1, it is an inequality that is easily deduced, but it doesn't seem very useful to me. The condition is much stronger, so it is clear that this is not enought. Sorry, but what you did can't be called solving the inequality. Please, if anyone has other solutions, let me know.

Comment: @JosieMcLaren Okey, this was my only idea.

Comment: @taiwan12 Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is  problem 28003 published by Marius St\u{a}nean in [Problem 28003, Gazeta matematic\u{a}, Seria B, 126 (2021), no. 2].
Its solution is published in volume 126, no. 9. Marian Cucoane\c{s}
showed in [Asupra problemei 28003 din Gazeta Matematic\u{a} nr. 2/2021, Gazeta matematic\u{a}, Seria B, 127 (2022), no. 2, 60--61] that the inequality
$$
 \frac{a^2}{b^2}+ \frac{b^2}{c^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2} +kabc \ge k+3      \tag{*}\label{*}
$$
holds for all $k\le \frac{9+2\sqrt{14}}{3}$. An even stronger version
is due to Titu Zvonaru, who proved in  [Din nou despre problema 28003 din G.M.--B 2/2021, Gazeta matematic\u{a}, Seria B, 127 (2022), no. 10, 437--438](https://ssmr.ro/gmb/ultimul_numar)  that the largest $k$
for which inequality~\eqref{*} is true for positive numbers satisfying
$a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4$ is greater than or equal to $22/3$ and less than $8.2$.

His proof is rather computational. After deconditioning  by using the well-known transformation
$$
 a=\frac{2\sqrt{yz}}{\sqrt{(y+x)(z+x)}}, \ldots 
$$
and ordering the nonnegative variables $x$, $y$, $z$, one reduces the problem to showing that a homogeneous polynomial of degree six  is nonnegative when its arguments are so. This is achieved by pointing out four obvious inequalities whose addition gives the desired one.

Comment: For your last sentence: Actually, BW (Buffalo Way) is used there.  https://ssmr.ro/gazeta/gmb/2022/10/articol.pdf